# Saving data at a particular time on an existing SQL/UNIX system?

Tags: sql, unix, save

I've started using a database at work that is based off SQL and Unix.

I am surprised to learn, that if someone requests for a change to be made to their details at around 5PM or a certain date, then the person who is allocated the incident then has to WAIT until 5pm and make the changes manually.

I'm surprised a button that says 'Apply changes later' does not exist, there is only a 'Save' button.

I have seen complicated solutions using Java on stackoverflow, but I am not familiar with UNIX or SQL, and googling brings no results.

Would it be a simple fix?
 It wouldn't have to account for any time differences, and I'm assuming would just work off System clock; and I know Java has a calendar function that I assume works off the PC clock.

Comment: Something like [`WAITFOR TIME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187331.aspx) ?

Comment: That looks about right - Literally assuming you could copy the functionality of the save button and just add a line for WAIT FOR?

Comment: See examples, also you don't specify RDBMS you use

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions before you post tags. If they contain "DO NOT USE!", then do not use them.

Comment: When you say the "functionalty of the save button", what do you mean? Are you writing the queries in SQL? Then there should be no save button? Or do you have some kind of interface? What RDBMS is this?

Comment: WHen you cannot use a SQL solution (when possible you should use that), you can wrap the SQL xommands in a script and look at the Unix `at` command .

Answer (score 0):

## Java

Java does indeed have a sophisticated facility for scheduling a future task to be executed. See the [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) class.

Rather than specify a date-time, you pass the `schedule` method a number of nanoseconds, or milliseconds, or seconds, or minutes, or hours, or days. You also pass a `TimeUnit` enum instance to indicate which granularity.

And, yes, Java depends on the host operating system for its clock to track the date-time.

## Task Master

I suggest using your database to track the jobs to be run, in conjunction with Java. If using only Java, the scheduled jobs would exist only in memory and would disappear if the Java app exits or crashes.

Instead, the Java app on launch should check the database for any pending jobs, and schedule them with an executor. Each job on completion should mark the database "task master" table row as finished.